# Run multiple oracle queries by PowerShell

Tags: oracle, powershell

I want to run oracle query through PowerShell. Single line query is running fine with no error. But now I have to run multi-line query.

```
set lines 400
select name,host_name,status,open_mode,to_char(startup_time,'DD-Mon-yy HH24:MI:SS') STARTUP_TIME from v$inst,v$db;
```

I tried this

```
$sql=@(
"set lines 400
select name,host_name,status,open_mode,to_char(startup_time,'DD-Mon-yy HH24:MI:SS') STARTUP_TIME from v`$inst,v`$db"
)
```

And multiple options but it is giving me error ORA-00922.

I am using ODP.net in PowerShell.

Please advise.

**Update:**

If I run this query in oracle(without PowerShell) then it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your $SQL Variable is an Array with only one line:

```
$sql.Count
1
```

Try create it in that way:

```
$sql = @()
$sql += 'set lines 400'
$sql += 'select name,host_name,status,open_mode,to_char(startup_time,''DD-Mon-yy HH24:MI:SS'') STARTUP_TIME from v`$inst,v`$db"'
```

> Important Note:

When using 'Quotes' inside the string you should add ''Dobule Quoutes'' otherwise it will be illegal - like this: `''DD-Mon-yy HH24:MI:SS''`

Comment: Let me try. Voted up. Now i am getting this error. "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

Comment: ORA-00900 was due to syntax error. Now I follow the same instruction provided by you and it is giving me ORA-00922. After this line $reader=$command.ExecuteReader()

Comment: If i simply check the $sql value then it is giving me query with no error

Comment: Script is not going till there (foreach or Outline). It is giving me error at executereader(). However, I tried to run this code $sql=@()
$sql += 'set lines 200'
$sql += "select Username,User_ID from dba_users" but it is also giving me same error.

Comment: If i simply run this $sql= "select Username,User_ID from dba_users" then it is giving me output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86870/discussion-between-avshalom-and-404).